# Show product variation as single product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a woocommerce shop with 3 products (rolling lawns). These products have many different pricing configurations based on geolocation (for delivery) of the customer and quantity(meters) selected. So for all the different quantity levels (below 60 meters, below 100 meters,...) and the zip code I have a product variation for this product with its own price. Now a requirement is that on a specific page I have to show, based on the input of zip code and quantity, a product which the user can add to cart. The price has to adapt to the input of course, thats why I want to use the variation which has the price per meter and multiply it with the quantity. I cannot figure out how to display the needed variation as a product where the customer can click "add to cart". Is this possible? Or have I failed the topic and should solve this a total other way and not with variations?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? To use product variations you just set it as a variable product and create the variations... it should work out of the box.

Comment: You can separate variations as different products but that is long process. Since you want to treat them as separate products just make them separate single products. " I want to use the variation which has the price per meter and multiply it with the quantity" You can use simple product qty as meter and multiply it.

Comment: @Shoelaced Yes, I know how to setup the product variations it all works for me, my requirement is a bit off tho, because I have to be able to show a product with the updated price of a specific variation and add to cart without selecting any variation details. I know I can hack this myself with custom code but does it work natively somehow?

Comment: @MartinMirchev hm yeah I thought so... sadly when I started I didnt have the requirement I have now and thats why my product variations are a misfitting design decision... I guess you are right I have to use simple products and somehow integrate my locatoin data into the product with ACF or how would I add custom data that affects the price dynamically?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're trying to accomplish, but to minimize custom coding you might look into a plugin like Booster for WooCommerce to see if it has the feature you need.

Comment: There are plugins that can make variable products as separate on shop/category listing.  But if you insist how to do it - remove all variable products from shop/catalog. Then i would populate the variations by using $product->get_children(); which will return the variations and load the template. Also i would suggest to have custom field for title in each variation if you want to be unique. As for the url by default will be https parent product url /?attribute_type=something which from SEO point is not grt and here comes the tricky part.